# Help understanding MVVM pattern?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, prism, viewmodel

I'm trying to get up to speed with using WPF and the Prism framework which is heavily associated with the MVVM pattern. I've ready many different descriptions, examples and discussions on MVVM and each one is slightly different and has left me a little confused.

**My understand is as follows:**

The MVVM pattern has 3 parts to it :-

- Model - the classes that hold the application data/information.
- View - The visual elements of the application.
- ViewModel - The logic, state and other behaviour associated with the visual elements. It takes data from the model and exposes it (possibly with some data conversion/formatting) in such a way that the View can use it directly.

**What I'm not sure about is:**

1. Do these 3 parts cover every part of the application? Or can there be parts of the application that are outside these 3 parts?
2. Is it the ViewModel or some other part that is responsible for populating the Model?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Absolutely not.  Unless they do.  If your application is simple, then everything can be handled in the View, ViewModel or Model(s).  If your application is complex, and best practices dictate you break out logic into their own types (communication logic, repository logic, etc), then there is no stopping you.  MVVM is only concerned with view-centric logic within the View, application logic within the ViewModel, and the means of storing information for transmission between the two.
2. The ViewModel is solely tasked with interpreting user actions and readying the results of logic within Models so that the View may display this information to the user.  In some cases, it makes sense that a Model itself hold some logic so that it may respond to user actions.  However, it has been my experience that this mini-ViewModel-Model design is in reaction to design decisions by inexperienced developers. Once you get the real hang of MVVM, you usually don't have to (or want to) put any code in your Models apart from validation logic.

Answer (score 0):

1. Think of Model, ViewModel and View as logical layers that handle Business, application flow and presentation respectively. For example, a ViewModel *class* may delegate complex or reusable UI interactions to a separate service that doesn't correspond to any particular view but still belongs to ViewModel *layer*.
2. Yes, ViewModel stands between UI and Model.